# Go: start HTTP server asynchronously but return error if startup failed

Tags: http, go, goroutine

I would like to start an HTTP server in a goroutine but have a its parent return an error if the startup failed. Is there a good way for doing this? I tried passing the error in a channel. But this makes the parent block even if the server started successfully (unless I introduce an arbitrary timeout for listening on that channel).

```
func Start() error {
  go func() {
     srv = &http.Server{...}
     if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
       // return err from Start()
     }
  }
  // return nil if server started successfully
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with using an arbitrary timeout? `ListenAndServe` blocks until the server shuts down; by wrapping what is *not* a `Start` function in a `Start` function, you're changing the semantics of the call, and you're going to have to account for that somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListenAndServe is a helper function that opens a listening socket and then serves connections on that socket.

Startup errors in ListenAndServer are in the listen part of the function.  Create the listener on the main goroutine and handle errors there. Run the server in a goroutine:

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080") // adjust arguments as needed.
if err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}

srv = &http.Server{...}
go func() {
   if err := srv.Serve(l); err != nil {
       // Handle non-startup errors here.
 }()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stick to that pattern, either send a `nil` error through the channel to signal a successful initialization or close the channel. Both actions can be picked up by the main thread and it will stop being blocked.

Comment: So when would you send `nil` into that channel? Before `srv.ListenAndServe()`? Well, no error will have occurred by then. Or after `srv.ListenAndServe()?` Well, this will only happen once the server has shut down again, so it does not really solve the issue at hand.